# Firebase Auth REST API: OAuth sign-in with Twitter gives error 32 "could not authenticate you"

Tags: node.js, twitter, firebase-authentication, twitter-oauth, node-request

I'm writing a function in Node.js to log a user into Firebase using Twitter credentials, via the REST API (requests are made using the [request](https://github.com/request/request) library). I'm able to use the Twitter credentials to post a tweet, but attempting to sign in to Firebase with `/accounts:signInWithIdp` is returning the following error:

```
{ error: 
   { code: 400,
     message: 'INVALID_IDP_RESPONSE : Failed to fetch resource from https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json?include_email=true, http status: 401, http response: {"errors":[{"code":32,"message":"Could not authenticate you."}]}',
     errors: [ [Object] ] } }
```

This is my code:

```
loginWithOAuth = (idToken, postBody, onCompletion, onError) => {
    var form = {
        postBody: querystring.stringify(postBody),
        requestUri: 'request uri',
        returnIdpCredential: 'false',
        returnSecureToken: 'true',
    }
    request.post({
        url: 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithIdp?key=' + firebase_api_key,
        body: form,
        json: true
    }, (error, r, body) => {
        // ...
    });
}
```

where `postBody` is of the form

```
{
    access_token: 'token',
    oauth_token_secret: 'token secret',
    providerId: 'twitter.com'
}
```

My Twitter app has permission to access user emails. I've also whitelisted the `requestUri` in both Firebase and Twitter. Regenerating my app & user keys doesn't make a difference.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

`postBody` is not a stringified object, it is URL encoded:

```
var form = {
    postBody: 'access_token=[TWITTER_ACCESS_TOKEN]&oauth_token_secret=[TWITTER_TOKEN_SECRET]&providerId=twitter.com',
    requestUri: 'request uri',
    returnIdpCredential: 'false',
    returnSecureToken: 'true',
}
```

Comment: Yes, I've tried that as well. Sorry if it wasn't clear but `qs` refers to `querystring` which url-encodes objects.